# How do I hide routes I don't control from ServiceStack's SwaggerFeature?

Tags: servicestack, swagger, swagger-ui

In my example, I'm using the `ApiKeyAuthProvider` and `RegistrationFeature,` which both add new routes to my metadata.

I want to use swagger as our main documentation for these services, but I don't want things like `/AssignRoles` showing up there.

I was exploring the OperationFilter, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what to do there.

What can I do to hide these unwanted routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [.NET Attributes at runtime](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#dynamically-adding-route-attributes) to control the visibility of services you don't control with ServiceStack's built-in [Restriction attributes](http://docs.servicestack.net/restricting-services), e.g. to only allow the attributes to be visible for localhost you can add restriction attributes to the specific Request DTO's in your AppHost:

```
typeof(AssignRoles)
  .AddAttributes(new RestrictAttribute { VisibleLocalhostOnly = true });
typeof(UnAssignRoles)
  .AddAttributes(new RestrictAttribute { VisibleLocalhostOnly = true });
```

To hide it for all requests you can set the visibility to none:

```
typeof(AssignRoles)
  .AddAttributes(new RestrictAttribute { VisibilityTo=RequestAttributes.None });
typeof(UnAssignRoles)
  .AddAttributes(new RestrictAttribute { VisibilityTo=RequestAttributes.None });
```

Note they'll still be shown in development mode when `Debug=true` which is automatically enabled for **Debug** builds, to simulate a release build you can set it to false, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    DebugMode = false
});
```